# Using JWT (in cookies), Google OAuth, Passport and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm using Passport and Google OAuth in a Node/Express server to authenticate my React app. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to redirect the Google callback to the frontend, because when I do the cookies that I'm setting (containing the authentication token) simply disappear. I can see the cookie being set, but then the redirect from the Node callback refreshes the page and they disappear.

Before showing you the code it's worth mentioning that this is being done over localhost, so that might be the reason that the cookies aren't persisting, but that doesn't make sense to me because I can see them being set in the first place.

Here are my route handlers:

```
this.router.get(
      `${this.path}/google`,
      passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
        session: false,
      })
    );
    this.router.get(
      `${this.path}/google/callback`,
      passport.authenticate("google", { session: false }),
      this.googleOAuth
    );
```

This.path is /auth. Then the handlers themselves:

```
 private initializeGoogleStrategy() {
    passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
          callbackURL: `${this.path}/google/callback`,
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          try {
            const existingUser: IUser = await this.user.findOne({
              "google.id": profile.id,
            });
            if (existingUser) {
              // we don't need to do anything
              return done(null, existingUser);
            }

            const newUserByGoogle = await this.user.create({
              method: LoginMethods.google,
              google: {
                id: profile.id,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
              },
            });
          } catch (error) {
            done(error, false, error.message);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

private googleOAuth = async (
    request: express.Request,
    response: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
  ) => {
    this.createTokenAndAttach(request.user, response);
// as soon as this redirect happens the cookie in the browser disappears

    response.redirect("/");
  };

  private createToken(user: IUser): TokenData {
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60; // an hour
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    const dataStoredInToken: DataStoredInToken = {
      _id: user._id,
    };
    return {
      expiresIn,
      token: jwt.sign(dataStoredInToken, secret, { expiresIn }),
    };
  }

  private createTokenAndAttach(user: IUser, response: express.Response) {
    const tokenData = this.createToken(user);
    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [this.createCookie(tokenData)]);
  }
```

On the react side of things, I'm using a proxy that looks like this:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    ["/auth/google", "/auth/current_user"],
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:5000",
    })
  );
};
```

My React app is running on localhost:3000.

I'm doing this to trigger the callback in the React app:

```
  <>
    <h1> I'm the landing page</h1>
    <a href="/auth/google">Click this</a>
  </>
);
```

What I would like to happen is when the user clicks the link, they authenticate with google, which calls the callback and simply takes the React app to / with the cookies set.

What is instead happening is when the user clicks the link and authenticates, the cookie with the token gets set, but then the redirect refreshes the page, and the cookie disappears.

If there's anything that I'm missing I'd really appreciate help with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: I had the exact same problem a couple of months ago, but, unfortunately, I don't really remember how I solved it exactly. Also I didn't use passport, so I had a finer control over setting cookies. `localhost` it definitely not a problem, it has something to do with cookie security. Does passport set `SameSite` attribute for cookies? That could be the issue. Also I was using `fetch` API and I had some issues with settings `credentials` field correctly. Maybe that could apply here? I'll post another comment if I find something else

Comment: Thanks @AlexChashin, I'll see if I can use the samesite attribute